# Data Grid View Binding Complex Type using code first entity framework

Tags: c#, winforms

We are using Code First Entity Framework in Desktop Application, And we created one to zero relationship like Company -> Product, Package Type -> Product, Product Type -> Product. So we have created all the master form for Company, Package Type, Product Type, but when we are going to bind data for company etc then it will show error because we have make relationship with company and product. Our entity like that

```
public class Company : Common
{
    public int CompanyID { get; set; }        
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }

    public virtual Product Products { get; set; }
}

public List<Company> Get(string search)
    {
        using (EF6CodeFirstContext db = new EF6CodeFirstContext())
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(search))
                return db.Companies.ToList();
            else
                return db.Companies.Local.Where(x => x.CompanyName.ToLower().Contains(search)).ToList();
        }
    }

Datagridview1.DataSource = Obj.Get(strSearch);
```

So, Please help me if there is any way to bind direct datagridview without using any type of loop.

Comment: pls post the whole error-message

Comment: Sorry, the objectcontext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations. But not resolved, actually we have used  using (EF6CodeFirstContext db = new EF6CodeFirstContext()) block due to this reason instance was disposed, so we define the "EF6CodeFirstContext" at the top and problem resolved.